# how to get value from javascript object in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am sending data from a web based application to a WCF RESTful service.

The value that I am sending is `[object Object]` but I am struggling to figure out how to convert the value in C# to be able to use the real value.

when logged the value `[object Object]` is `Object {a: "GBasQLwJcDidphr/1Chumg=="}`.

Comment: Looks like json. Have a look at a json parser in c#

Comment: serialize it to json before pass to c# from javascript

Comment: You can use the package Newtosoft to parse json in c# http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: You can skip the manual deserialization at the server if your WCF operation takes a Type that makes use of [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use:

```
 var json = JSON.stringify(YourObject);
```

And pass this in request.

Then at server side, 
Add a reference of `Newtonsoft.Json.dll and use`JsonConvert` to deserialize the json string into object as

```
var targetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeOfTargetObject>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Here's my code
`var a = [{g : 'test'}, {z : 'asd'}];
  var b = [{g : 'test'}, {z : 'asd'}];
  
  var json = JSON.stringify(a);
  var json1 = JSON.stringify(b);`

the object is not in JSON, is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

On client side:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(objectToSend);
```

On Server side:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(jsonString);

public class Example
{
    public string a { get; set; }
}
```